Displaying state name to the AmCharts 5 Map
Using AmCharts 5 in react application to display the US geographic. I can able to view the states in US Geography, but unable to add the state name to the map. But on hovering of the state, i can able to display the state name in the tooltip. Is there a way to add the state name to any Geographic in amCharts5
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as am5 from '@amcharts/amcharts5';
import * as am5maps from '@amcharts/amcharts5/map';
import usaHigh from "@amcharts/amcharts5-geodata/usaHigh";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";

const MapChart = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create root element
    let root = am5.Root.new("mapDiv");

    // Set themes
    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    let chart = root.container.children.push(
        am5maps.MapChart.new(root, {
          projection: am5maps.geoAlbersUsa(),
          maxZoomLevel: 16,
          minZoomLevel: 1,
          zoomStep: 1.2,
        })
      );
    const polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
      am5maps.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
        geoJSON: usaHigh
      })
    );

    polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
      tooltipText: "{name}",
      templateField: "polygonSettings",
    });
     }, []);

return <div  id="mapDiv" style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }}></div>;
};


